# Query to select a post and all attachments

Tags: python, mysql

So, I have this forum I am building. I'm having trouble writing an elegant select query to get all the posts for a certain topic from the db. Here's the schema:

Table posts have the following structure:

```
   id int(5) not null auto_increment,
   user_id int(5) not null,
   topic_id int(5) not null,
   post_date datetime not null,
```

Now, there's also a table called attachments, where post attachments are referenced. I want to be able to select the attachments of a particular post with just one query. Here's the attachments table structure:

```
   id int(5) not null auto_increment,
   post_id int(5) not null,
   post_name varchar(255) not null default '',
   path varchar(255) not null,
```

This is not what my tables look like really. I just want a basic idea how to do it. I can't even think of the least of solutions. Now the attachment table has a foreign key that references the post table. But, a post could possibly have many attachments. So how do I select a post and all its attachment in just one query? Maybe subqueries could work?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM attachments WHERE post_id in (SELECT id FROM posts WHERE topic_id = ?);
```

Something like this?

Edit:
Not what the poster wanted after all. I don't think it is possible to do what you want with your table structure, without using more than one query.

Comment: i was talking of selecting the post with  all the attachments in just one query

Comment: I dont know if this should work?? SELECT t.id, t.user_id, (SELECT * FROM attachments WHERE post_id = t.id) attach FROM posts

Comment: You said: "I want to be able to select the attachments of a particular post with just one query.". If that is not what you want, please edit your question.

Comment: You should read the last part of the question "So how do I select a post and all its attachment in just one query?"

Comment: You can't really do that in one query. SQL returns rows with the fields you choose. If a post has more than one attachment, and you do a join of some sort, you would get multiple rows back for the post.

Comment: Ok, so whats the best way you think i go about it? Please